# Data structure to search a List of items containing a word faster than Linq's implementation

Tags: c#, .net, search

I have a simple class:

```
public class RepositoryItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool Public { get; set; }
}
```

And a `List<RepositoryItem>` that contains millions of these objects. I want to be able to search through this list for a query. Currently, I use a simple approach: `list.Where(r => r.Title.Contains(query))` but this is very inefficient. I would use a `Dictionary` but want to search for partial queries. Meaning if the title is `Hello` I want to be able to find it with the `query = "hel"`. Is there any data structure that does this faster than `List<>` and `Linq`?

Comment: You might want to look into a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) and some variation on a [suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree)

Comment: @juharr won't Trie use lots of memory? Currently, the server uses around 6GB of RAM for the `List<>`

Comment: Yes, the trade off is space for speed, but then why not implement something in a DB instead?  For example if you had a table of title suffixes with a many to many relationship to the items, then you can do a starts with comparison that could use an index on the suffix table.

Comment: @juharr I would appreciate a sample implementation/more details

Comment: at some point you may even want to consider using a search engine such as http://lucenenet.apache.org/